# Why might Google Fusion Tables sqlGet queries stop working after Google+ sign-in through gapi.auth?

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-oauth

I'm writing a page that uses OAuth 2.0 via gapi.auth.authorize to authenticate a Google+ user and gapi.client.request to run Google Fusion Tables sqlGet queries.  I find that my queries run fine before authentication, but then fail with a 403 "Insufficient Permission" error when run more than 30 seconds 
after authentication.

The problem is demonstrated with this page:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B5Urq1jZb1MYSWloU3NTY2M4Qnc/test3b.htm

Please follow these steps:

1. Click "Query" to run a gapi.client.request Google Fusion Table SQL-get query returning a count of rows. This will run successfully until OAuth is used in steps 2 and 3.
2. Click "Start OAuth" to run an immediate:true authorization against Google+. If you are currently signed into Google+, your user name and ID will be displayed in the third button.
3. If your Google+ user name is not displayed in the third button, click the button ("Authorize") and sign into Google+.
4. Click the "Query" button again. The query will run without error when pressed within about 30 seconds of OAuth authorization. After that, the query fails with a 403 error. WHY?

Here is the source for the demo page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Test3b</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var g_domIsReady = false;
        var g_gapiIsReady = false;

        $(function () {
            log("@$(function())");
            g_domIsReady = true;
            start();
        });

        function gapiIsReady() {
            log("@gapiIsReady");
            g_gapiIsReady = true;
            start();
        }

        function start() {

            // Make sure both the gapi.client and the DOM (per jquery) are ready.

            if (!(g_gapiIsReady && g_domIsReady)) return;

            // Define members.

            log("@start - gapi and DOM are ready");

            var m_apiKey = "AIzaSyAvb0NHQMwyPbMJRtz2zRL4wTiVjZDiois";  // Points to Google account (including Google Drive) at paloalto@geodesy.net.
            var m_clientId = "868768273487-q295tdfr54uvo98v74891qakcr9ci0pf.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            var m_scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";

            // Wire buttons.

            var queryButton = document.getElementById('query-button');
            queryButton.onclick = function () { runGetRequest(); return false; };
            var startOAuthButton = document.getElementById('startOAuth-button');
            startOAuthButton.onclick = function () { startOAuth(); return false; };

            // Set-up the gapi.

            gapi.client.setApiKey(m_apiKey);

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // gapi.client.request query functions.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            function runGetRequest() {
                log("@runGetRequest");
                var tableId = "1VZgvKyuh9uHXkQawpxg1MU8AlO8Mngl-sx7SP74";  // TR_TREE_E
                var sql = "select count(GID) from " + tableId + " where GID > 50000";
                var path = "/fusiontables/v1/query";
                var restRequest = gapi.client.request({
                    path: path,
                    params: { 'sql': sql }
                });
                restRequest.execute(jsonCallback);
            }

            function jsonCallback(json) {
                log("@jsonCallback");
                var output = JSON.stringify(json);
                log(output);
                alert(output);
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // OAuth functions.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            function startOAuth() {

                log("@startOAuth");

                var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
                window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);  // check auth in 1 ms

                function checkAuth() {
                    log("@checkAuth");
                    gapi.auth.authorize({
                        client_id: m_clientId,
                        scope: m_scopes,
                        immediate: true
                    }, handleAuthResult);
                }

                function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                    log("@handleAuthResult");
                    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                        log("@handleAuthResult - authResult=true");
                        log(authResult);  // authResult is a token (with 3600 second expiration).
                        authorizeButton.disabled = true;
                        useAuthResults();
                    } else {
                        log("@handleAuthResult - authResult=false");
                        authorizeButton.disabled = false;
                        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
                    }
                }

                function handleAuthClick() {
                    log("@handleAuthClick");
                    gapi.auth.authorize({
                        client_id: m_clientId,
                        scope: m_scopes,
                        immediate: false
                    }, handleAuthResult);
                    return false;
                }

                function useAuthResults() {
                    log("@useAuthResults");
                    // Get the Google+ user's ID and name (member info).
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
                        log("@gapi.client.load callback");
                        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({ 'userId': 'me' });
                        request.execute(function (aInfo) {
                            log("@request.execute callback");
                            if (aInfo.code !== undefined) {
                                alert('Google+ API returned ' + aInfo.code + ': ' + aInfo.message);
                            } else {
                                // Here with successful sign-in.  Display the user name.
                                log('Google+ user id, name: ' + aInfo.id + ', ' + aInfo.displayName);
                                authorizeButton.value = aInfo.displayName + " +" + aInfo.id;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }

            }
        }

        function log(msg) {
            if (console) console.log(msg);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=gapiIsReady" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test3a</h1>
    <p>This pages demonstrates a problem I am having using gapi.client.request with gapi.auth.</p>

    <input type="button" id="query-button" value="Query"><br>
    <input type="button" id="startOAuth-button" value="Start OAuth"><br>
    <input type="button" id="authorize-button" value="Authorize"><br>

    <p>Steps...</p>
    <p>1. Click "Query" to run a gapi.client.request Google Fusion Table SQL-get query returning
    a count of rows.  This will run successfully until OAuth is used in steps 2 and 3.</p>
    <p>2. Click "Start OAuth" to run an immediate:true authorization against Google+.  If you
    are currently signed into Google+, your user name will be displayed in the third button.</p>
    <p>3. If your Google+ user name is not displayed in the third button, press it ("Authorize")
    and sign into Google+.</p>
    <p>4. Click the "Query" button again.  
    The query will run without error when pressed within about 30 seconds of OAuth authorization.
    After that, the query fails with a 403 error.  WHY?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Please note that I intend to use the Google+ sign-in to track page usage specifics by user, not to enable the Fusion Tables queries.

I'm new to OAuth and gapi.client.request so this may be a simple misunderstanding on my part.
Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the answers for you, but here I think are some that may help:

1. Before you have the user sign-in with G+, the gapi.client.request object is adding a "key=yourAPIKey" parameter to each request.
2. After you have the user sign-in with G+, the gapi.client.request object is adding a "key=yourAPIKey" parameter to each request *and* is sending an "Authorization: Bearer ya.xxxxxx" header with each request, representing an access token for the user that is logged in.

I think the reason you're seeing a 403 is because the access token is being sent to the server, but the token does not include a scope authorizating access to FusionTables data. When no access token is sent - this validation is not performed.

If you actually wanted to access data that the user owned, then you need to have the user consent to give your application access to their data by including an appropriate scope in your gapi.auth.authorize call (e.g. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables").

However since I don't think you are trying to access data on behalf of a specific user, what I think you really want to do is prevent the "Authorization" header being sent at all during your call to Fusion Table API.

I can't see an easy way to prevent the gapi.client.request library from sending that header when the user is logged in, so an alternate solution might be to instead create an HTTP object not using the gapi.client.request library (e.g. use XMLHttpRequest directly) - and manually include the "key=yourAPIKey" in each request.

(What I can't explain is why you're seeing 30 seconds of differing behavior...)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, aeijdenberg.  You're right, my page doesn't need access to the user's fusion tables, and I'd like not to ask them for that permission.  I have tried using a jQuery $.ajax() XHR call in place of the gapi.client.request call and not only does that work, it somehow opens up another ~30 second window of error-free operation for the gapi.client.request queries!
But $.ajax() appears to have CORS problems in IE8 and IE9 during FT SQL POST operations.  Maybe I need to give up my hopes for gapi.client.request queries and look for ways around my $.ajax() problems.